# how to know when a select finds 0 rows mysql, getFetchSize() not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, authentication

I am trying to make a username only register if that name is not taken, using JDBC connection and checking on SQL Database. 
I have the code that checks for the 
    SELECT * FROM user 
    WHERE username = 'jessica';

and it finds 2 rows;

Searched a lot and found that with getFetchSize() it would give me the number of rows, and if it finds null it would return 0. 
It is always returning 0, I don't know why, because I have the usernames taken twice, it lets me add me always... 
https://prnt.sc/galyqo

```
 public int nameAvailable(MyUserApp app, String name) throws SQLException{
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM user \n WHERE username = '"+ name +"';";
    Statement st = app.getCon().createStatement();
    ResultSet rs =  st.executeQuery(sql);
    int numResults = rs.getFetchSize();

    return numResults;
}
```

This is the register code:

```
private void RegisterButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    String username, password, address, dob;
    boolean status;
    String u;
    try {

        username = newUsernameField.getText();
        password = passwordField2.getText();
        address = addressField.getText();
        dob = dateofbField.getText();
        int no= 5;

        if( username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 6 ){
            jLabel6.setText("The information you typed in is not valid. ");
            status = false;
            showTableDB.setText(""+status);
        }    
        else{
                no = this.app.nameAvailable(app, username);
                jLabel6.setText(no+"");
                if(no == 0){
                    jLabel6.setText("Registered your account, "+username+"!" + no);
                    status = this.app.registerUser(app, username, password, dob, address);
                    u = this.app.showInfo(app, username);
                    showTableDB.setText(u);
                    no = this.app.nameAvailable(app, username);
                }
                else{
                    showTableDB.setText("That username is token. Please choose a different one.");
                }


                }


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UserAppUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UserAppUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Resolved.        Solution:

```
public int getNCount(MyUserApp app, String name) throws SQLException{
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user \n WHERE username = '"+ name +"';";
    int rowCount;
    PreparedStatement st = app.getCon().prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    ResultSet r =  st.executeQuery(sql);
    r.next();
    // get the number of rows from the result set. On the db it will show a table with "count(*)" and the #counts
    rowCount = r.getInt("count(*)"); 
    r.close();
    st.close();
    return rowCount;
}
```

By calling these statement on the code:

```
r.next()
```

and then

```
rowCount = r.getInt("count(*)");
```

I was able to get the 2nd column of the count(*) SQL Statement.

Comment: Jessica, the whole idea of having plain SQL statement being used within your JAVA code is an approach you should revise (many reasons, like establishing a heavy dependency between the structure of your data and your JAVA code). I would suggest you handle the registration attempt via a stored procedure, which will receive all the required parameters and will return a result code (e.g. 0 - zero- would indicate success, 1 would indicate duplicate, 2 would indicate missing data, etc.). Yes, I know I'm not answering/addressing your question, but (so I believe) I'm giving a more valuable help.

Comment: @FDavidov  Thank you, I solve this situation before, thanks for helping me, I don't know how to do that with storage procedure, but I did a couple (2 or 3) of storage procedures a year ago, I'll take a look into that;

 I solved the registration just now as well, I have an SQL statement that checks SELECT *  .. WHERE username = ? and password = ?  
And It works. What I understand you are telling me is that I should not have that code inside JAVA and create a storage procedure and then call it on the JAVA code, right?. Idk how to call storage procedures on java code, gotta learn first... :)

Comment: You are welcome. And yes, avoid using explicit SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements within your JAVA code. As for calling stored procedures from JAVA, there are lots of examples. Quite simple to do it. Just google a little and you'll find them. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fetch size is not the same thing as the number of rows.  The fetch size is just a way of limiting how many rows at a time will be fetched from the database.

There's no easy way to check the number of rows returned by a `select` statement.  If you really need to know how many rows there are, in the case there's more than one, then one approach would be to iterate through the result set, copying the information that you need from each row into memory; then check the amount of data that you copied at the end.

Alternatively, if you don't actually need any data from the rows themselves, you could try a statement like `SELECT count(*) FROM user WHERE username = ?`.

One more thing - you need to read about SQL injection attacks.  This is where a hacker uses your code to run SQL that they shouldn't.  The code you've shown here is vulnerable to an SQL injection attack.  But that's another question entirely.

Comment: Yes, I'll try that, and this actually is for that purpose of study, first I need to make it work then I'll study sql injections, what a coincidence you refering to that :) hope i finish this app tomorrow

Comment: Cool.  Good luck with your ongoing studies, Jessica.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really need to learn more and do better always

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Solution:

```
public int getNCount(MyUserApp app, String name) throws SQLException{
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user \n WHERE username = '"+ name +"';";
int rowCount;
PreparedStatement st = app.getCon().prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet r =  st.executeQuery(sql);
r.next();
// get the number of rows from the result set. On the db it will show a table with "count(*)" and the #counts
rowCount = r.getInt("count(*)"); 
r.close();
st.close();
return rowCount;
```

}

By calling these statement on the code:

```
r.next()
```

and then

```
rowCount = r.getInt("count(*)");
```

I was able to get the 2nd column of the count(*) SQL Statement.